# How to get browser name WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, browser, service

How do I get the string name of the browser (Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, ...) which Visual Studio opens when executing a WCF service?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012

The problem is that I'm using curl to test my service, and browser name is unknown when I use

```
HttpRequest Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

string Browser = Request.Browser.Browser.ToString();
```

When I run my WCF Service it opens a browser. How do I get that browser name in Program?

Comment: There is no browser when you use curl -- it doesn't use a browser.  The `HttpContext` class determines the browser by the User Agent property.

Comment: but when I start my wcf service if opens a browser, how do I get that browser name

Comment: but that's a Visual Studio thing ... the WCF service itself, as well as any of its client programs, know nothing about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (Request.Browser.Type.Contains("IE")) // replace with your check
{
    ...
} 
else if (Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("Chrome")) // replace with your check
{
    if (Request.Browser.MajorVersion  < v1)
    { 
        DoSomething(); 
    }
    ...
}
else { }
```